# jupyter giving 404: Not Found error on WIndows 7

Tags: python, jupyter

I installed anaconda PYTHON 2.7 64bit on Win 7 and then updated using

```
conda update conda
```

Later installed

```
conda install jupyter
```

When I tried to run from the same drive on windows using

```
jupyter notebook
```

it launches on Firefox and states

```
404: Not Found
```

On the command it says

```
Refusing to serve hidden directory via 404 Error
```

What needs to be done to get it launched?

Update:
The anaconda install has a shortcut to run jupyter and it works that way - but gives 404 for "jupyter notebook":

```
d:\Anaconda\Scripts/ipython-script.py" notebook
```

Comment: Hello I am currently on **windows 7**. To solve the problem i set **google chrome** as my default browser. It worked just fine.

Answer (score 27):

I found a simple cause of this could be trying to run Jupyter from the root of a drive - running it from C:\ failed. Cricboy007's suggestion to create a folder (no particular name, I called mine notebook) and run Jupyter once you've used cd to make that the working directory worked for me.

Comment: Strangely I had this problem with Anaconda but not Winpython distribution. With anaconda, you should not be on a root of a drive.

Comment: I had the same problem running Jupyter with Anaconda.

Comment: this solved my problem as well, created a new directory in D: drive and followed this tutorial -> http://technivore.org/posts/2016/02/27/windows-jupyter-three-ways.html

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same 404 error and solved it by doing the following:

right click the jupyter notbook shortcut > properties > change the value of "Start in:" to a path within your Anaconda install (e.g., D:\Anaconda2\Notebooks).

If you are running from the command line, changing directory to within the anaconda folder should work too

Answer (score 1):

Well as it says it refuses to serve a hidden directory. Try launching it from a non-hidden directory.

Comment: How is it hidden? I launched it from D dir - Anaconda is in d:\Anaconda\ - Which one is a non-hidden dir?

Comment: Well I got it working now by changing dir - how can I set path? Path D:\Anaconda\Scripts\ was added on install?

Comment: Please post your answer or check the right existing answer.

Answer (score 1):

Manually change the directory to Anaconda2.
eg. cd Anaconda2
then run - jupyter notebook

Comment: Worked for me :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on Windows 7, python 3 and IE as a default browser. After fighting and changing many setting, i finally changed the default browser to Chrome and the  it showed properly the page.

Answer (score 1):

I meet this case.when I try to open jupyterlab,Anaconda tells me this:

```
[I 10:01:41.587 LabApp] The port 8888 is already in use, trying another port.
[I 10:01:41.587 LabApp] The port 8889 is already in use, trying another port.
[I 10:01:41.588 LabApp] The port 8890 is already in use, trying another port.
[I 10:01:41.608 LabApp] JupyterLab beta preview extension loaded from D:\Anaconda\install\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab
[I 10:01:41.608 LabApp] JupyterLab application directory is D:\Anaconda\install\share\jupyter\lab
[W 10:01:41.619 LabApp] Error loading server extension jupyterlab
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Anaconda\install\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\commands.py", line 321, in __init__
self._run(['node', 'node-version-check.js'], cwd=HERE, quiet=True)
File "D:\Anaconda\install\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\commands.py", line 1165, in _run
proc = Process(cmd, **kwargs)
File "D:\Anaconda\install\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\process.py", line 73, in __init__
self.proc = self._create_process(cwd=cwd, env=env)
File "D:\Anaconda\install\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\process.py", line 131, in _create_process
cmd[0] = which(cmd[0], kwargs.get('env'))
File "D:\Anaconda\install\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\jlpmapp.py", line 59, in which
raise ValueError(msg)
ValueError: Please install nodejs 5+ and npm before continuing installation. nodejs may be installed using conda or directly from the nodejs website.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Anaconda\install\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 1454, in init_server_extensions
func(self)
File "D:\Anaconda\install\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\extension.py", line 111, in load_jupyter_server_extension
info = get_app_info(app_dir)
File "D:\Anaconda\install\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\commands.py", line 244, in get_app_info
handler = _AppHandler(app_dir, logger)
File "D:\Anaconda\install\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\commands.py", line 324, in __init__
raise ValueError(msg)
ValueError: Please install nodejs 5+ and npm before continuing installation. nodejs may be installed using conda or directly from the nodejs website.
[I 10:01:41.709 LabApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: C:\Users\user
[I 10:01:41.709 LabApp] 0 active kernels
[I 10:01:41.710 LabApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 10:01:41.710 LabApp] http://localhost:8891/?token=a3d823839f1107857f79c15ae9d6a109b046b98621186073
[I 10:01:41.710 LabApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 10:01:41.711 LabApp] 

Copy/paste this URL into your browser when you connect for the first time,
to login with a token:
http://localhost:8891/?token=a3d823839f1107857f79c15ae9d6a109b046b98621186073
[I 10:01:41.761 LabApp] Accepting one-time-token-authenticated connection from ::1
[W 10:01:41.833 LabApp] 404 GET /lab?token=e0fc453fcb7d3a4a22f7042bacf336bea5e90678af55b72f (::1) 72.00ms referer=None
```

and chrome shows 404:Not Found.when I open the jupyter in anaconda,I also meet case like that.
so I update jupyterlab and jupyter,then all become good.Therefore,this case might be version problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, as mentioned above the issue was being in the root directory. I just have a bad habit of immediately starting at the root directory when I open CMD. If I leave it in the user folder so it runs as C:\Users[me]>jupyter notebook it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You must first set the environment variables:
**C:\Windows\system32>conda create --name test_jupyter**
**Proceed([y]/n)? y**
**C:\Windows\system32>activate test_jupyter**
**(test_jupyter) C:\Windows\system32> jupyter notebook**
it will appear in your default browser..

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue from command line (Windows 10). Here is what I did to resolve it:

1. Fully uninstall Anaconda
2. Remove respective PATH / ENVIRONMENT variables
3. Reinstall Anaconda (I did just for myself, not for all users)
4. Search for DESKTOP application "Jupyter Desktop" and start it
5. Voila:  Jupyter is up and running!

Answer (score -1):

For windows 7, anaconda installed by Admin profile. Shortcut created for user(s) had wrong users\folder in "Start in" (working directory) in the start menu folder.
Correct the "Start in" entry for the shortcut and it works.

Also watch out for users\*username*\.anaconda\navigator\defaults-1.0.0.ini, with similar path entry.

Answer (score -1):

What I did:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /path/to/my/folder
```

and it resolved all the issues.