# Jupyter Lab "404 : Not Found You are requesting a page that does not exist!"

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-lab

Jupyter Notebook and Jupyter Lab worked well until I updated packages and set environments.
After that, JupyterLab 3.0 doesn't open. It shows 404 and an error message:

```
[I 18:21:13.532 LabApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from 
C:\Users\Alfonso\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\jupyterlab
[I 18:21:13.532 LabApp] JupyterLab application directory is C:\Users\Alfonso\AppData\Roaming\Python\share\jupyter\lab
[W 18:21:13.533 LabApp] Error loading server extension jupyterlab
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 2036, in init_server_extensions
        func(self)
    File "C:\Users\Alfonso\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\jupyterlab\extension.py", line 226, in load_jupyter_server_extension
        add_handlers(web_app, config)
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab_server\handlers.py", line 162, in add_handlers
        handlers.append((url_pattern, LabHandler))
    AttributeError: 'NotebookWebApplication' object has no attribute 'append'
[I 18:23:27.282 LabApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: C:\Users\Alfonso
[I 18:23:27.282 LabApp] Jupyter Notebook 6.3.0 is running at:
[I 18:23:27.282 LabApp] localhost:8889/…
[I 18:23:27.283 LabApp] or 127.0.0.1:8889/…
[I 18:23:27.283 LabApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 18:23:27.370 LabApp] To access the notebook, open this file in a browser: file:///C:/Users/Alfonso/AppData/Roaming/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-5876-open.html
```

[image]

I changed the browser (Firefox instead of Chrome), followed the suggestions in another post ([How to solve 404 error of jupyter lab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48948259/how-to-solve-404-error-of-jupyter-lab)), but neither worked. Also, I've tried to fix the problem by installing as administrator and as user.

I was wondering if there's a solution that not involves reinstalling all Anaconda distribution.

Installed versions:

- `jupyterlab` 3.0.11
- `jupyterlab_server` 2.4.0
- `notebook` 6.3.0

Comment: There is a clear error message in your output when running jupyterlab. Please copy-paste it here - pictures of code are not accessible. Please also list the versions of jupyterlab, notebook, and jupyter_server (if present) that you have installed. You can do this using `conda list` command or `pip list` (depending how you installed them)

Comment: [I 18:21:13.532 LabApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from C:\Users\Alfonso\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\jupyterlab
[I 18:21:13.532 LabApp] JupyterLab application directory is C:\Users\Alfonso\AppData\Roaming\Python\share\jupyter\lab
[W 18:21:13.533 LabApp] Error loading server extension jupyterlab
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 2036, in init_server_extensions
func(self)  [1/3]

Comment: File "C:\Users\Alfonso\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\jupyterlab\extension.py", line 226, in load_jupyter_server_extension
        add_handlers(web_app, config)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab_server\handlers.py", line 162, in add_handlers
        handlers.append((url_pattern, LabHandler))
    AttributeError: 'NotebookWebApplication' object has no attribute 'append'
[I 18:23:27.282 LabApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: C:\Users\Alfonso
[I 18:23:27.282 LabApp] Jupyter Notebook 6.3.0 is running at: [2/3]

Comment: [I 18:23:27.282 LabApp] http://localhost:8889/?token=799aa4d28f5afcf799d55fd6f9a872bf0dd070f2edc50ad9
[I 18:23:27.283 LabApp]  or http://127.0.0.1:8889/?token=799aa4d28f5afcf799d55fd6f9a872bf0dd070f2edc50ad9
[I 18:23:27.283 LabApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 18:23:27.370 LabApp]

    To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
        file:///C:/Users/Alfonso/AppData/Roaming/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-5876-open.html
    [3/3]

Comment: jupyterlab                3.0.11     |        
jupyterlab_server         2.4.0    |       
notebook                  6.3.0      |

Comment: It looks iike https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab_server/issues/146 but slightly different. It seems that you have multiple versions of these conflicting packages installed, in two places:
- `C:\Users\Alfonso\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages`
- `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages`
So packages that you installed via pip conflict with those installed via conda. Try `pip uninstall jupyterlab` and then `conda install -c conda-forge jupyterlab`

Comment: It worked! 
I think I had tried the same before... but! Now, works! 
Thanks, man!

Comment: Great! I will reformat your question and add an answer so it is easier for others to follow in case if someone else gets the same issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Someone else experienced a similar problem when they had conflicting  `jupyterlab_server` and `jupyterlab` version installed (see [issue 146 in jupyterlab_server repository](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab_server/issues/146)), however your versions are fine. At a closer look the issue is with **where** they are installed:

The traceback includes paths to two locations:

- `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages`
- `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages`

It indicates that you may have multiple versions of these packages installed in different places (a newer version installed in the local Python directories via `pip`, and an older version in the Anaconda3 directory installed via `conda`). Because conda on your system has a higher priority, when JupyterLab (installed localy) tries to import its dependencies, it gets the old version of `notebook` and `jupyterlab_server` from conda directories, which cannot do what it wants.

Solution:

1. `pip uninstall jupyterlab`
2. `conda install -c conda-forge jupyterlab`

Context: There was an large infrastructure change in JupyterLab 3.0 meaning that it now uses `jupyter_server` and `jupyterlab_server` instead of `notebook` for all the backend work (interacting with kernels, filesystem, opening ports etc).