# How to fix 404 error in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, jquery, jupyter-notebook

I opened jupyter notebook from cmd prompt both in a new folder as well as a folder from which I had opened it before, however I am getting this error: [Error 404 in Jupyter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDvwi.png)

I looked at some other posts and tried to:

1. Fix the c.notebookapp.browser line in the jupyter config to Chrome which I use.
2. Update conda from the anaconda launcher
3. Install nodejs as mentioned in another answer
4. Installing react from the anaconda launcher, but gave a packages not found error
5. Opening with --ip="0.0.0.0"
6. Opening with a port different from 8888
7. Installing jquery since a lot of the error messages indicate jquery

I don't know what else to try, any help would be appreciated. When I open the link that is created I get Error 404: You are requesting a page that does not exist!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jupyter giving 404: Not Found error on WIndows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33031069/jupyter-giving-404-not-found-error-on-windows-7)

Comment: No, I was not on C or any root directory. I also tried the answer which suggests changing the starts in of anaconda, didn't change anything. I think that may not be related because it explicitly tells the people who experienced that problem "Refusing to serve hidden directory" and I don't get this message.

Comment: If you have a D: directory try changing your path to a `D:/your/path` kindoff directory for once, and add errors if any to your question

Comment: I don't have a D: directory. Should I create one?

Comment: no, let it be. How it you install jupyter notebook?

Comment: I researched a little bit about your errors, seems to me as a bug, on which devs said to be fixed in later versions. You could try updating jupyter-notebook, or reinstalling it. If its urgent you can use online solutions like `google colab` .

Comment: I don't remember exactly how but I have Ubuntu 18.04 (command line) on Windows. I installed conda and everything from there (afaik). I am running notebook using Ubuntu ever since. I tried updating jupyter notebook but the same error persists. I am considering completely reinstalling it (any suggestions?).

Comment: Have you ever launched jupyter notebook successfully from ubuntu terminal in windows?